# Experimental heat equation for a bottle of water

Tags: thermodynamics

I'm not sure if this question belongs here, because I'm asking a question about experimental data rather than theoretic formula.

Anyway, I'm trying to figure out the time-temperature relation of the (hot) water in an ordinary sports bottle. Assume the bottle is full with 500mL of water in it. Do you guys have any data for that? The equation doesn't have to be accurate, an error up to 20% can be accepted.

Comment: I could be wrong, but my guess is no one has data. Is anything stopping you from doing this yourself? It seems like a very simple experiment.

Comment: The time-temperature relation depends completely on the experimental circumstances, i.e. temperature difference between water and environment, what kind of bottle, wind, standing or lying bottle, etc. Without fixing a few of these parameters an error bound of 20% is not achievable.